# Search not working in devices

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a search box, when user enters any text and press enter or clicks on search icon it should redirect to search page.

Functionality is working fine in desktop, but only in android devices it is not working , if i press enter or clicks on search icon nothing happens.

I've tried adding focus, kepyess, touchstart but nothing helps. Please help

**Updated:**

I've identified that there are two search mockup one for desktop and another for mobile.

While searching in mobile device, input text value is null because it is taking the value of desktop search.

I've updated the script but still it is not taking the mobile input value. Please let me know what i'm doing wrong

```js
$(".newsroom_search-box,.newsroom_search-box_mobile").submit(setupNewsroomSearch);

$('.search_banner-q_newsroom,.search_banner-q_newsroom_mobile').click(function() {
  $('.search_banner-q_newsroom,.search_banner-q_newsroom_mobile').focus();
});


$(".search_desktop-newsroom-submit,.search_desktop-newsroom-submit_mobile").click(setupNewsroomSearch);


function setupNewsroomSearch(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  if ($(".search_banner-q_newsroom,.search_banner-q_newsroom_mobile").val().trim().length === 0) {
    return false;
  } else {
    alert('called');
    var tracking = '&ei=newsroom_search';
    redirectToSearchPage($(".search_banner-q_newsroom").val(), "newsroom", "commbank_all", tracking);
  }

}
```

```html
Desktop Mockup
<div class="newsroom-search-wrapper">
  <form class="newsroom_search-box">
    <div class="search-box">
      <input type="text" class="search_banner-q_newsroom" aria-label="Search" name="query" placeholder="${newsRoomBrowseContainerModel.searchText}" />
      <i class="icon-search search_desktop-newsroom-submit" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
Search Mockup
<div class="newsroom-search-wrapper_mobile mobile-search">
  <form class="newsroom_search-box_mobile">
    <div class="search-box">
      <input type="text" class="search_banner-q_newsroom_mobile" aria-label="Search" name="query" placeholder="${newsRoomBrowseContainerModel.searchText}" />
      <i class="icon-search search_desktop-newsroom-submit_mobile" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: which browser(s) on Android? Do you get any errors? This needs a bit more detail.

Comment: Default browser on Android 5, no errors in console

Comment: I've updated my question, issue here is i've two search mock when i enter some text in mobile it take the desktop input value which null that is the reason why nothing happens when i hit enter.

Comment: now the issue is, i've updated my script to take the mobile input value, but it still take desktop value

Comment: `redirectToSearchPage($(".search_banner-q_newsroom").val()` is probably the reason. But I think your design approach is wrong. You've got two almost identical snippets of HTML - same DOM structure, only a couple of classes different. Instead, write the HTML once, and use CSS media queries to make different definitions of the classes so the HTML appears differently depending on the screen size. And then you can use the same JavaScript in both scenarios too. The way you've got it now is a recipe for confusion, as you're discovering.